# Make my thinkpad battery discharge when it hits upper threshold even while plugged in (TLP)

Tags: laptop, linux-mint, battery, thinkpad, battery-life

I just installed TLP on my Thinkpad x230 running Linux Mint. A colleague suggested it for optimizing battery life. My expected behavior (based on my understanding of his description of battery life best practice) is to charge up to a max of 90%, then discharge to 75%, then repeat, while my laptop is plugged in. (If I'm barking up the wrong tree, please let me know).

The following are the relevant lines in my `/etc/default/tlp`:

```
START_CHARGE_THRESH_BAT0=75
STOP_CHARGE_THRESH_BAT0=90
```

All other settings in `/etc/default/tlp` are the package defaults.

Currently, when plugged in, my battery remains at a constant 89% (according to the indicator on my Mint taskbar). Am I missing something?

For reference, here's the output from `sudo tlp-stat -b`:

```
--- TLP 0.8 --------------------------------------------

+++ ThinkPad Extended Battery Functions
tp-smapi   = inactive (kernel module 'tp_smapi' load error)
tpacpi-bat = active

+++ ThinkPad Battery Status: BAT0 (Main / Internal)
/sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/manufacturer                   = LGC
/sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/model_name                     = 45N1025
/sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/cycle_count                    = (not supported)
/sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/energy_full_design             =  62160 [mWh]
/sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/energy_full                    =  43700 [mWh]
/sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/energy_now                     =  39120 [mWh]
/sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/power_now                      =      0 [mW]
/sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/status                         = Unknown (threshold effective)

tpacpi-bat.BAT0.startThreshold                              =     75 [%]
tpacpi-bat.BAT0.stopThreshold                               =     90 [%]
tpacpi-bat.BAT0.forceDischarge                              =      0
```

Comment: From what I've read, 45-50% is optimal from Lenovo battery team - https://pointieststick.com/2020/06/08/lenovo-thinkpad-x1-yoga-impressions-bugs-workarounds-and-thoughts-about-the-future/#comment-22688

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're trying to achieve is pure nonsense. You don't want to constantly wear your battery by cycling it while on AC power. Besides it won't work because charge thresholds control charging (as the name implies) not discharging. Their purpose is to prevent small charge cycles only.

Please have a look at the [TLP FAQ](http://linrunner.de/en/tlp/docs/tlp-faq.html#battery) too.

Comment: Thanks. I have edited the question to make it clearer that I was seeking confirmation/rejection of my understanding of the threshold behavior: "expected" behavior instead of "desired" behavior. You could have substituted "is not desirable behavior" in place of "pure nonsense."

Comment: Old post but cycling is actually good for long life 
https://batteryuniversity.com/article/bu-808-how-to-prolong-lithium-based-batteries

Lenovo Battery team say 45-50% while on AC
https://pointieststick.com/2020/06/08/lenovo-thinkpad-x1-yoga-impressions-bugs-workarounds-and-thoughts-about-the-future/#comment-22688

Answer (score 0):

For completeness, as I was also having the same question and then I found this post, the description in the [documentation](https://linrunner.de/tlp/faq/battery.html) says:

> "Limiting the maximum charge level to below 100%: **stop charge threshold**; After a short discharge, prevent the charging process from continuing as soon as the charger is connected: **start charge threshold**".

From this, I inferred the same as you regarding discharge and charge cycles: that it would charge up to the stop threshold, then *let discharge* down to the start threshold, and then charge up again until the stop threshold, repeating.

After reading carefully, what actually happens is this: if it's above the start threshold (even past the stop threshold, which can happen if you used `tlp fullcharge` for instance), the battery will hold charge. Only if it is below the start threshold the battery will initiate charging up to the stop threshold.

I didn't get initially the need of having two thresholds, but once again it's in the docs: *"After a short discharge, prevent the charging process from continuing as soon as the charger is connected"*. The goal is to prevent charging cycles due to short disconnect periods.